# NHibernate - Any type mappings - "how do i query the meta-values?" or "how does meta-type="class" work?"

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I use NHibernate 3.3.3 and have a class mapping that uses the "Any type mappings" described in 5.2.4 of the NHibernet documentation.

It currently looks like this:

```
<class name="AttributeValue" table="AttributValue">
  <id name="Id" column="ID" type="int" >
    <generator class="MyGenerator" />
  </id>
  <property   name="Value"    column="Value"      type="string" length="255"/>
  <many-to-one name="AttributeDef" column="AttributDef_ID" />

  <any name="Reference" id-type="Int32" meta-type="Int32">
    <meta-value value="1" class="MxObject"/>
    <meta-value value="500" class="Material"/>
    <meta-value value="5" class="Company"/>
    <meta-value value="10" class="Fluid"/>
    <meta-value value="10040" class="Contract"/>
    <meta-value value="504" class="Tool"/>

    <column name="Kontext"/>
    <column name="Oid"/>
  </any>
</class>
```

My entity looks like this:

```
public class AttributeValue
{
    public AttributeValue() { }
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Value { get; set; }
    public virtual AttributeDef AttributeDef { get; set; }
    public virtual object Reference { get; set; }     
}
```

The other entities referenced in the  mapping have a collection that points to the AttributeValue Entity like this:

```
public virtual ICollection<AttributeValue> AttributeValueList { get; set; }
```

And the mapping looks like this:

```
<bag name="AttributeValueList">
  <key column="OID"/>
  <one-to-many class="AttributeValue"/>
</bag>
```

Everything is working as intended. I can query all the stuff i need, i can save it just fine.

Here is my problem. I'm writing a test that takes every entity in my model and writes a dummy version with random data to the database using reflection and iterates recursively through the references to other entities and creates them as well. Everything works fine up until i hit that property of the AttributeValue entity.

```
public virtual object Reference { get; set; }
```

I just don't know how to figure out how to query the metadata or the mapping to find out what possible entities to put into that Reference property.

I tried to get the meta-values this way:

```
    var metadata = session.SessionFactory.GetClassMetadata(typeof(AttributeValue));
    var pType = metadata.GetPropertyType("Reference") as AnyType;
    var mType = (pType.Subtypes[0]) as MetaType;
```

But the MetaType class doesn't expose the dictionaries holding that particular information and i don't really see a way to just get a list of possible classes out of it.

I also tried it via the

```
cfg.GetClassMapping(typeof(AttributeValue))
```

route but i only end up getting an instance of the MetaType class again.

Is there a way to query that particular information?

If not maybe there's another way?

I found in the NHibernate documentation this example:

```
<any name="AnyEntity" id-type="Int64" meta-type="Eg.Custom.Class2TablenameType">
    <column name="table_name"/>
    <column name="id"/>
</any>
```

If i see that right then i could make a class that holds this information and pass it on as the meta-type attribute. I then could just query that class to get the information i want.

I just don't know how to implement this Class2TablenameType class and the documentation isn't really clear on it (at least i don't really understand it) how to do it.

Help would be appreciated.